# How can I straighten a curve in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe where "Original" is what I have and "Target" is where I would like to straighten it approximately to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Original': [0, 6, 14, 23, 49, 100],
    'Target': [0, 10, 25, 40, 65, 100],
    'Linear': [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
})
df.plot()
```

How can I also define the degree of straightening, like Target is 45% straightened and Linear is 100% straightened (and Original 0% straightened)?

[image: plot]

Comment: When you say straighten towards target, what do you have in mind? One could theoretically use the `target` values and write to `original` to have it match exactly, or are we imagining that we have some `original` set of data and we want to find a way to make it resemble the `target` from the image, without necessarily having that column in the dataframe?

Comment: I would like to use original and somehow straighten it to resemble the target.

Comment: Linearly interpolate between `linear` points and `original` points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interpolate between your original data and the linear data. Empirically, a weight of 0.475 gives a pretty close approximation.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Original": [0, 6, 14, 23, 49, 100],
        "Target": [0, 10, 25, 40, 65, 100],
        "Linear": [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
    }
)
weight = 0.475
df[f"Weight_{weight}"] = df["Original"] * (1 - weight) + df["Linear"] * weight
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Or, `Original + (Linear - Original) * weight` which I find much easier to understand (The answer above is an algebraic manipulation of the formula here, to reference a scalar twice instead of referencing a vector twice.)

Answer (score -3):

Try making this update in your code. I think this will solve your problem. Make any alterations you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Original': [0, 6, 14, 23, 49, 100],
    'Target': [0, 10, 25, 40, 65, 100],
    'Linear': [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
})

df.plot(label=['Original', 'Target', 'Linear'])
plt.xlabel('Original = 0% | Target = 45% | Linear = 100%')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Straightening Comparison')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want. With straighten, I mean "bend it towards a linear curve"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).